# My main navigation pages doesn't show me preview

Tags: templates, dynamics-crm, portal

In Microsoft Dynamics 365 Power Pages, I am trying to create a portal using a template
After it is created, I'm trying to edit the pages on Main Navigation
However, when clicked any main navigation, it doesn't show me the preview of the page

[image]

It says to refresh the pages after a while, however i tried to refresh it for an Hr.
Still doesn't work